# content_for blank when logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing (more or less) [WordPress's concept of shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in my Rails app. The problem is that when I `:yield` anything in my layout defined via `content_for` in the view, it's just blank. So the additional javascript and title tags are not rendered.

In other words, calling `content_for? :title` in the layout returns false.

This only happens <del>in posts/index, and **only when I'm logged in**</del> **when the `filter_shortcodes` helper is run.** Has anyone encountered something like this before?

In views/posts/index.html.haml:

```
- content_for :script do
    = javascript_include_tag '/assets/autoload.js'

- content_for :title do
    Blog
...
= render template: 'article-content',
```

And in views/article-content.html.haml (`filter_shortcodes` is a helper function defined in the `Shortcode` module.):

```
:plain
    #{filter_shortcodes instance.content}
```

I remain convinced that the problem is in my shortcode module, so here it is, back by unpopular demand:

```
module Shortcode
    def filter_shortcodes content
        content.gsub /(?<!\\)\[.+\]/ do |code|
            # A shortcode must:
            #   - be on its own line
            #   - be [contained within square brackets]
            #   - be named using only lowercase letters
            # If it contains parameters, they must come in the form:
            #   key="value"
            shortcode = /^\s*\[(?<name>[a-z]+) (?<params>.*)\s*\]\s*$/.match code

            params_list = shortcode[:params].gsub /&quot;|"/, '"'

            param_regexp = /([a-z]+)="([^"]*)"/
            shortcode_params = {}
            params_list.scan param_regexp do |param|
                shortcode_params[param[0].to_sym] = param[1]
            end

            render_to_string template: "shortcodes/#{shortcode[:name]}",
                :locals => shortcode_params, layout: false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: We don't need to see your filter_shortcodes module, but the layout where you yield the contents would be nice to see.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question to include the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it *was* a problem with the shortcode module. Basically, `render_to_string` behaves like render, and you can only make one call to *either* in a controller action. So, because `filter_shortcode` was behaving as a controller method (through the module's inclusion in my controller class), `render_to_string` violated the once-only principal.

It'd be nice if Rails enforced this the way they do when you try to call `render` twice, but maybe this is an edge case?

Anyway, my solution was to render a cell instead of a template. The below code is a little more verbose, but it's also more robust because it allows you to do shortcode-specific validation:

lib/shortcode.rb:

```
module Shortcode
    def filter_shortcodes content

        # A shortcode must:
        #   - be on its own line
        #   - be [contained within square brackets]
        #   - be named using only lowercase letters
        #   - be unescaped (not preceded by a "\")
        # If it contains parameters, they must come in the form:
        #   key="value"
        regex = /^\s*\[(?<name>[\w]+)\s+(?<params>([^\]]+\s*)*)?\](?<contents>([^\[])*)?(\[(\\|\/)[a-z]+\])?$/

        # Here's the negative lookbehind for the escaping \
        content.gsub /(?<!\\)\[.+\]/ do |code|

            shortcode = regex.match code
            # return shortcode[:params]
            params = get_params shortcode
            params[:contents] = shortcode[:contents] if shortcode[:contents].present?

            if ShortcodeCell.method_defined? shortcode[:name]
                # just spit out the content if the template doesn't exist
                begin
                    render_cell :shortcode, shortcode[:name], params
                rescue ArgumentError => error
                    "[#{shortcode[:name]} ERROR: #{error.message}]"
                end
            else
                "Unsupported shortcode: #{shortcode[:name]}"
            end
        end
    end

    def get_params shortcode
        # hack to render quotes...
        params_list = shortcode[:params].gsub /&quot;|"/, '"'

        params = {}
        params_list.scan /([a-z]+)="([^"]*)"/ do |param|
            params[param[0].to_sym] = param[1]
        end

        return params
    end
```

cells/shortcode_cell.rb:

```
class ShortcodeCell < Cell::Rails
    def soundcloud args
        if args[:url].blank?
            raise ArgumentError.new 'missing URL'
        end

        render locals: args
    end
end
```